# Find a field by its name in a Library

Tags: list, lookup-column

So I'm having an error:

> The field "Document_x0020_Type" contains a lookup to list
>   "{D2589081-9361-4393-996B-7C156C7B8F5A}" that cannot be resolved. The
>   target list may not be part of this site.

I figured I should know in which list this field is. I know it is in a Documents library, but how can I find where is field is, so I can look at the problem directly?

Alternatively, do you have any straightforward solution to that error?

Comment: Go to List Settings, and look the columns where type is Lookup - and check how many lookup columns are there...

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen before when we have moved a site..especially when moving from one farm to another. The problem is with GUIDs..isn't it always? :) After moving the subsite we have noticed that lookup columns were not working as expected and had no/blank values for the list/column they were originally linked to. This awesome [powershell function](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/01/fixing-blank-lookup-columns-in.html) helps fix these broken links. This will only restore the lookups. It doesn't restore the data to the list/library, so you will then have to go (most likely through opening with access) and copying all of the appropriate values for each item. Let me know if you have any additional information so I have a better idea of what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

To get a better look at the fields and list, you can use the SharePoint Manager utility up on CodePlex: http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/51438.  This lets you browse through the structure of your SharePoint instance on a more granular level.  Be sure to run it on the SharePoint server and run as administrator.